# Flutter - How to check if a package in pubspec.yaml is in use?

Tags: flutter, dart, package, dependencies, pubspec.yaml

I have imported different packages during the development process to pubspec.yaml's dependencies section. Currently I am not using some of them, but not sure which ones. Is there an easy way to check if a package is used in any of the files?

Should I check all of the files for all packages?

Comment: 1. delete a dependency, run `flutter pub get` if there are no errors, it is not in use
or 2. search in the whole project directory for occurences of the package name, if they only appear in the pubspec.yaml or at least not in any dart files it is probably not used.

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://pub.dev/packages/dependency_validator lib
Add in pubspec.yml

```
dev_dependencies:
  dependency_validator: ^3.0.0
```

Run in terminal

```
dart pub run dependency_validator
```